# How do I implement OIDC authentication in Blazor WebAssembly?

Tags: authentication, openid-connect, identity, blazor, webassembly

I am working on a PoC Project to verify blazor to be the right technology for our company internal web frontend applications. We have an internal identity provider (IdentityServer4 impl.) which I want to authenticate with. In the older projects where angular is being used, we use the javascript oidc client with implicit flow. As far as I understand OIDC, implicit flow should be perfectly fine for a blazor WebAssembly single page application. We have no dedicated server application for that particular frontend, just a few microservices where the frontend fetches data and therefore needs to provide an access token.

An OIDC client library or some example code (ideally both) would be really helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Implicit flow should now be avoided: https://medium.com/oauth-2/why-you-should-stop-using-the-oauth-implicit-grant-2436ced1c926

Comment: Correct [Authorization Code Grant with Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE)](https://auth0.com/blog/oauth2-implicit-grant-and-spa/) is the new standard recommendation

Comment: See also my answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58983153/blazor-spa-authenticating-with-auth0-fails-on-callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to give a try to [Blazor.Auth0](https://github.com/henalbrod/Blazor.Auth0) (author here).

> Blazor.Auth0 is a library for using the Authorization Code Grant with Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE) with Auth0's Universal Login in Blazor SPAs.

If you're not interested in adding/using a third-party service then at least the source code would help to drive you in the correct path.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi Henri, I browsed quickly the source code, where do you take care of the authorization code (before the token request)? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I was in a situation where I needed an extendable library for Blazor WebAssembly supporting OpenID Connect (OIDC) with Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE). Therefore, I have created the open source [ITfoxtec.Identity.BlazorWebAssembly.OpenidConnect](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.BlazorWebAssembly.OpenidConnect) library which is JavaScript free and pure .NET.