# Blazor SPA authenticating with Auth0 fails on callback

Tags: asp.net-core, auth0, blazor

I’m writing a basic Blazor app following [this blog post](https://auth0.com/blog/what-is-blazor-tutorial-on-building-webapp-with-authentication/#Securing-the-Application-with-Auth0) and I've struck difficulty with the /callback redirect in the actual Blazor application. The error I’m seeing is

> OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'invalid_grant', error_description: 'Invalid authorization code', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'

at the /callback URL.

[image: ASP.Net Core exception screen]

If I check the logs, I can see there are three events happening at the Auth0 end:

- Successful login
- Authorization Code for Access Token
- Invalid authorization code

Each straight after the other. I can see those authorization codes do match between the “Success Exchange” and the “Failed Exchange” entries.

I can see Auth0 authentication has actually taken place, and if I browse to other pages in my app, I can see I have logged in successfully, but that initial callback to the /callback URL stops things in their tracks. Is there something missing in the middleware / Startup.cs code, or are there additional things to check for the Auth0 application settings?

For the avoidance of doubt, I've copied the blog post code exactly and can confirm the application *does* authenticate and log me in. Here's the code in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
    services.AddSingleton<ClubInformationService>();

    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    // Add authentication services
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie()
    .AddOpenIdConnect("Auth0", options =>
    {
        // Set the authority to your Auth0 domain
        options.Authority = $"https://{Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}";

        // Configure the Auth0 Client ID and Client Secret
        options.ClientId = Configuration["Auth0:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Auth0:ClientSecret"];

        // Set response type to code
        options.ResponseType = "code";

        // Configure the scope
        options.Scope.Clear();
        options.Scope.Add("openid");

        // Set the callback path, so Auth0 will call back to http://localhost:3000/callback
        // Also ensure that you have added the URL as an Allowed Callback URL in your Auth0 dashboard
        options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/callback");

        // Configure the Claims Issuer to be Auth0
        options.ClaimsIssuer = "Auth0";

        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
        // handle the logout redirection
        OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = (context) =>
            {
            var logoutUri = $"https://{Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}/v2/logout?client_id={Configuration["Auth0:ClientId"]}";

            var postLogoutUri = context.Properties.RedirectUri;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(postLogoutUri))
            {
                if (postLogoutUri.StartsWith("/"))
                {
                // transform to absolute
                var request = context.Request;
                postLogoutUri = request.Scheme + "://" + request.Host + request.PathBase + postLogoutUri;
                }
                logoutUri += $"&returnTo={ Uri.EscapeDataString(postLogoutUri)}";
            }

            context.Response.Redirect(logoutUri);
            context.HandleResponse();

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        } //... etc.
```

Not sure that it adds a lot to the problem, but the diagnostics leading up to the exception being thrown look like the following:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2 POST https://localhost:5001/callback application/x-www-form-urlencoded 396
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[10]
      AuthenticationScheme: Cookies signed in.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 634.9692ms 302
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2 POST https://localhost:5001/callback application/x-www-form-urlencoded 396
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[52]
      Message contains error: 'invalid_grant', error_description: 'Invalid authorization code', error_uri: 'error_uri is null', status code '403'.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[17]
      Exception occurred while processing message.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'invalid_grant', error_description: 'Invalid authorization code', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.RedeemAuthorizationCodeAsync(OpenIdConnectMessage tokenEndpointRequest)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[4]
      Error from RemoteAuthentication: Message contains error: 'invalid_grant', error_description: 'Invalid authorization code', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'..
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
 ---> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'invalid_grant', error_description: 'Invalid authorization code', error_uri: 'error_uri 
is null'.
```

Comment: These two lines were the first I've noticed in your app: services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();  HttpContext is not available in Blazor Server, and the call to AddHttpContextAccessor is futile. I do not claim that this is the issue, but you know...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You may be right about those lines of code but unless there's something there that contributes specifically to this question's problem, I don't feel that your suggestion really helps move this post closer towards an answer.

Comment: Your code seems the same as the official tutorial.Maybe there's something wrong in other place? for example, [this issue](https://github.com/auth0/react-native-auth0/issues/224#issuecomment-517612168) turning the email to lower case causes to a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to add Auth0 in a Blazor WebAssembly project, you could just use the [documentation from Microsoft.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

However when using this for Auth0, there is one catch:

- It's not possible to provide the **Audience**, this means that you need to apply this work-around : [Auth0-why-is-it-necessary-to-pass-the-audience-parameter-to-receive-a-jwt](https://community.auth0.com/t/why-is-it-necessary-to-pass-the-audience-parameter-to-receive-a-jwt/11412)

Or you can use my NuGet package : [WebAssembly.Authentication.Auth0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebAssembly.Authentication.Auth0) which does support the **Audience** parameter.

More details van be found here:
https://github.com/StefH/Blazor.WebAssembly.Authentication.Auth0